# Docker: Unable to edit code within image due to missing bash

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 18 running on an AWS server.  Within that server I have a Docker image that I want to change the code for while it is still running.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-79:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
fc                         latest              20949d0fd7ec        7 days ago          1.74GB
debian                     latest              8d31923452f8        5 weeks ago         101MB
ekholabs/face-classifier   latest              b1a390b8ec60        21 months ago       1.77GB
```

In order to change the code I ran the following command

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-79:~$ docker run -it fc bash
```

But I get the following error

```
python3: can't open file 'bash': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I go about fixing this so I can edit the code within the Docker image.  As a side note here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git python3-pip python3-dev python3-tk vim procps curl

#Face classificarion dependencies & web application
RUN pip3 install numpy scipy scikit-learn pillow tensorflow pandas h5py opencv-python==3.2.0.8 keras statistics pyyaml pyparsing cycler matplotlib Flask

ADD . /ekholabs/face-classifier

WORKDIR ekholabs/face-classifier

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:src
ENV FACE_CLASSIFIER_PORT=8084
EXPOSE $FACE_CLASSIFIER_PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["src/web/faces.py"]
```

Comment: Typically I’d make a change in my local development environment, test it, `docker build` a new image, and delete and restart my container.  Deleting containers is extremely routine, and trying to directly edit code in a container is just asking for work to be lost.

Comment: @DavidMaze That makes sense.  Wouldn't that end up wasting a lot of time since it takes a while to build?  Like I don't want to do all that work just to find I made a small syntax error.  Maybe I misunderstand something

Comment: Run unit tests like `pytest` locally, outside of Docker, before you start the `sudo docker build && docker run` sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your dockerfile you use an

> ENTRYPOINT ["PYTHON3"]

which means when you run

> docker run -it fc bash

it gets converted inside container to "python3 bash" this is why you have an error

> python3: can't open file 'bash': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Try remove the ENTRYPOINT

Hope that resolve the problem.